# What do i need to do in order to get a random generated array with user input, and then enter two indexes where it swaps them?

Tags: c#, arrays

So basically Im writing a code where the user inputs the size of the array and the array generates random numbers, and then the user will enter 2 indexes where it will swap the indexes.

So far i only got the main part. Please help me. I got everything right except when i try to print on the swapped index array, it gives me an error.

```
using System;
    class MainClass
{
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
        int[] randomSizedArray;
        string sizeOfArray;
        int convertedSizeArray = -1;
        Console.WriteLine ("Please Enter the Size of the Array Between 1-99");
        sizeOfArray = Console.ReadLine();
        convertedSizeArray = Int32.Parse(sizeOfArray);
        ;   
        randomSizedArray= new int[convertedSizeArray];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i < convertedSizeArray; i++) {

        randomSizedArray[i] = rnd.Next(1,99);


        }
            for (int i=0; i < convertedSizeArray; i++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(randomSizedArray[i] + "");
}
        string swapindex1;
        string swapindex2;
        int index1;
        int index2;
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Index to swap");
        swapindex1 = Console.ReadLine();
        index1 =  Int32.Parse(swapindex1);
        int temp = randomSizedArray[index1];
        Console.WriteLine ("Please Enter a Second Value to swap");  
        swapindex2 = Console.ReadLine();
        index2 =  Int32.Parse(swapindex2);  
        randomSizedArray[index1] = randomSizedArray[index2];
        randomSizedArray[index2] = temp;
         Console.WriteLine(randomSizedArray[temp] + "");
    }   


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So say you need random numbers between 0 and 10.

```
array = new int[convertedSizeArray];
for (int i=0; i < convertedSizeArray; i++) 
{
    array[i] = rnd.Next(11);
}
```

Then you can ask for two numbers the same way you ask for the array length and switch them

```
int temp = array[index1];
array[index1] = array[index2];
array[index2] = temp;
```

If you want to print an int you have to do `Console.WriteLine(randomSizedArray.ToString())` or `Console.WriteLine(randomSizedArray + "")`

And if you want to print each number you can just print them like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < convertedSizeArray; i++) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(array[i] + "");
}
```

Comment: so array = new int[convertedSizeArray];
for (int i=0; i < convertedSizeArray; i++) 
{
    array[i] = rnd.Next(11);
} that generates the random number and then the int temp = array[index1];
array[index1] = array[index2];
array[index2] = temp; asks for the index swap and it switches, im confused.

Comment: the second part switches the numbers at the given indexes. You can get the two indexes from the user the same way you asked for the length of the array. I assumed you stored those values in `int index1` and 2

Comment: so i would use the index1=Console.ReadLine(); in order to get the index yeah?

Comment: well, yes. But don't forget to Parse it to an int value

Comment: If you want to print an int you have to do `Console.WriteLine(randomSizedArray.ToString())` or `Console.WriteLine(randomSizedArray + "")`

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, i keep on getting System.Int32[] everytime i type my size and press enter, but i dont know what

Comment: I modified my answer with my comment above

Comment: i will modify my question in order to ask you another question

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to achieve with this: `Console.WriteLine(randomSizedArray[temp] + "");`